# 1. Выведите имена студентов (fio_stud), их группы (name_tgroups), их оценки (mark) объединяя таблицы: students, groups, uploaded_homeworks

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT * FROM Students JOIN groups
                         ON Students.id_tgroups = groups.id_tgroups
                       JOIN uploaded_homeworks
                         ON groups.id_tgroups = uploaded_homeworks.id_domzadstud
```

соединил 3 таблицы, но ничего не выводит, что не так?

Comment: Связь верна? - groups.id_tgroups = uploaded_homeworks.id_domzadstud

Comment: хм, если чисто этот запрос, то ошибку выводит

Comment: не надо дублировать вопросы, почитайте книги.

Comment: Я же говорю, я прочитал, смотрел видео-уроки, ничего не получается, может здесь кто объяснит

Comment: На ваш вопрос невозможно ответить, не видя ваших данных. Запрос выглядит корректным. Если ничего не выводит, значит по указанным условиям соединения нет подходящих записей в базе. попробуйте убрать например второй join и убедитесь, что первый дает результаты, если нет - значит проблема уже в нем. вообще запрос, особенно если вы только начинаете изучать sql, надо писать постепенно, буквально пишите select * from x, проверяете что работает и смотрите что вывел. добавляете join, опять смотрите, что бы поймать тот момент когда данные уже не те, какие вы хотите получить

Comment: вот во втором join у вас условие выглядит странно. судя по названию колонок id_domzadstud  - это id домашнего задания, вы сравниваете его с id_tgroups, видимо с id группы. Что то я сомневаюсь, что домашнее задание и группа студентов это одно и то же

Comment: id_domzadstud   - уникальный идентификатор загруженного студентом домашнего задания, он же первичный ключ, с помощью которого Вы и будете объединять Ваши таблицы(после upload_homeworks./////я попробовал все поля, все равно ничего не получатется, хотя )первый join все верно выводит

Answer (score 1):

Я бы завязал все связи на студентов и применял такой запрос:

```
SELECT students.fio, groups.name_group, homeworks.mark  
FROM students 
INNER JOIN groups ON groups.students_id = students.id
INNER JOIN homeworks ON homeworks.students_id = students.id
```

Comment: спасибо, сделал уже)